# printing values that falls in the range of values using awk

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have a column of data saved in a text file `data.txt`, first of all i want to print the extreme minimum and extreme maximum value of that column and then

case1: i want to print the values that falls in the range -0.001 to +0.001.
In this case

```
    input
    0.5
   -0.5
    0.001
   -0.001
```

output

```
 0.001
-0.001
```

case2: i want to turn the values to fall in the range -0.008 to +0.008
in this case output should be as follows for same input

```
    0.005
   -0.005
    0.001
   -0.001
```

I tried the following oneliner,

```
awk '{print $1 > -0.001 && $1 < 0.001; print $0}' data.txt
```

it prints some values but i am not sure if it is doing correct things.I hope experts may will me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output

Comment: @anubhava added sir please have a check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a base on command line and use it like this:

```sh
awk -v base='0.001' 'NR>1 && $1 >= (-1 * base) && $1 <= base' file
0.001
-0.001

awk -v base='0.008' 'NR>1 && $1 >= (-1 * base) && $1 <= base' file
0.005
-0.005
0.001
-0.001
```

Where input file is:

```
cat file
input
0.005
-0.005
0.001
-0.001
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to print maximum and minimum of that column

Comment: additionally my input file is same as given in the question its not 0.005
-0.005
0.001
-0.001

Comment: input is 0.5
   -0.5
    0.001
   -0.001

Comment: sir please have a look the input which is little different from what you have mentioned in the answer  and case2 answer i didnot get .can you please suggest.Thanks

Comment: If input has `0.5` then how come your expected output has `0.005`?

Comment: by multiplying 0.01, which should be a automatic process thats why i need minimum and maxima sir

Comment: `by multiplying 0.01` This is not covered in your question. I suggest you clarify all requirements very clearly in question and show output is achieved.